# HTML I have a ">" before a table for no reason

Tags: html

I thought this might be a Dreamweaver error but it's apparently not.  I put a table on a page for links and for some reason there is an errant ">" just before the first line of the table.  To be exact, it's just above the table.  I just spent forever going line by line to see if there was a "<" without a corresponding ">" but there isn't.

Then I thought it must be caused by something above but the code above (library items) are the same on all my pages.  So I commented out the whole table and there is no ">" when I do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Have a great Turkey Day.

```
<tr>
  <td width="7"><div align="center"></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><strong>A</strong></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><strong>B</strong></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><strong>C</strong></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><strong>D</strong></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="7"><div align="center"><strong>1</strong></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><a href="https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/Customer/Code.aspx" tabindex="1" target="_new"><img src="../images/help.png" width="85" height="85" /></a></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com" tabindex="2" target="_new"><img src="../images/googlet.gif" width="210" height="87" /></a></div></td>>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/" tabindex="3" target="_new"><img src="../images/yahoo.gif" width="200" height="50" /></a></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><a href="http://www.amazon.com/" tabindex="4" target="_new"><img src="../images/amazon.gif" width="170" height="51" /></a></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="7"><div align="center"><strong>2</strong></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><h3><a href="mailto:paul@m-csi.com">E-Mail Paul Warren</a></h3></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><h3><a href="http://www.drudgereport.com/" target="_new" title="Drudge Report">Drudge Report</a></h3></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><h3><a href="http://www.kbaq.org/" title="KBAQ Classical Radio" target="_new">KBAQ<br />Classical Radio</a></h3></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><h3><a href="http://online.wsj.com/home-page" title="Wall Street Journal" target="_new">Wall Street Journal</a></h3></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="7"><div align="center"><strong>3</strong></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><h3><a href="http://www.whrb.org/" title="WHRB Harvard Radio" target="_new">WHRB<br />Harvard Radio</a></h3></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><h3><a href="http://www.masslandrecords.com/" title="Sec. Of State Galvin" target="_new">Sec. Of State<br />William Galvin</a></h3></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><h3><a href="http://www.lawlib.state.ma.us/" title="MA Trial Court Law Libraries" target="_new">MA Trial Court Law Libraries</a></h3></div></td>
  <td width="220"><h3 align="center"><a href="http://masslawyersweekly.com/" title="Massachusetts Lawyers Weekly" target="_new">Massachusetts<br />Lawyers Weekly</a></h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="7"><div align="center"><strong>4</strong></div></td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><h3><a href="http://www.lawlib.state.ma.us/subject/forms/index.html" title="MA Legal Forms" target="_new">MA Legal Forms</a></h3></div></td>
  <td width="220">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="220">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="220"><div align="center"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This only shows a part of the table markup. Can we see the rest?

Comment: When you see this Ctrl + F your code for `>>`. Fixed fast.

Comment: The error you made is detectable using [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`</td>>` on one of your lines (the google.com line). That second `>` is treated as plaintext OUTSIDE of the bounds of a `td` or `th`, so it'll generally be printed BEFORE the table itself.

In other words, you've got invalid HTML, so yes, there is a reason for the "bad" character...

Answer (score 0):

I actually found it...
Second `<tr>` Block, third `</td>` - closing tag.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you.  You found it!  I went through the whole thing twice going "open...close, open...close,"  I guess I was looking for a missing close instead of an extra one.  God I have so much to learn.  But with great people like you folks I just might make it.  I wish I could green check you all.  Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

`<td width="220"><div align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com" tabindex="2" target="_new"><img src="../images/googlet.gif" width="210" height="87" /></a></div></td>>`

needs to be:

`<td width="220"><div align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com" tabindex="2" target="_new"><img src="../images/googlet.gif" width="210" height="87" /></a></div></td>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com" tabindex="2" target="_new"><img src="../images/googlet.gif" width="210" height="87" /></a></div></td>>
```

Fixed:

```
  <td width="220"><div align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com" tabindex="2" target="_new"><img src="../images/googlet.gif" width="210" height="87" /></a></div></td>
```